# How to customize file right click actions on Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I need to execute a JS code on a `json` file when I right click on it using VSCode and show the result on a modal or on command prompt based on other code.

For example:

Code to execute (example.js) when right-clicking a json file:

```
function run(fileLocation){
   var file = require('./'+fileLocation);
   return file.length;
}
```

The example.json (file to be right-clicked):

```
[{id: a},{id: b},{id: c},{id: d},{id: e}]
```

Like the image below, it would appear on the menu like `Execute example.js` or something like this.

[image: Add code to right click actions on VS Code]

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 7):

For this, you'll need two contributions:

- A [command contribution](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.commands) your package.json that defines some basic info about the command. You'll also need a command registration in your source code that implements the command.
- A [menu contribution](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.menus) in the `package.json` for `explorer/context`. This should be linked to the command you defined.

All together, this would look something like:

// package.json

```
"activationEvents": [
    "onCommand:extension.doThing"
],
"contributes": {
    "commands": [{
        "command": "extension.doThing",
        "title": "Do the thing",
        "category": "My Extension"
    }],
    "menus": {
        "editor/title": [{
            "command": "extension.doThing",
            "group": "navigation"
        }]
    }
}
```

// in your extension source

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

vscode.commands.registerCommand('extension.doThing', (resource: vscode.Uri) => {
    ...
})
```

Comment: If you want your menu item to appear in the context of the Explorer then use "explorer/context", instead of "editor/title"